# How to encode a unicode string (ones from JSON) to 'utf-8' in python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I am creating a REST API using Flask-Python. One of the urls (/uploads) takes in (a POST HTTP request) and a JSON '{"src":"void", "settings":"my settings"}'. I can individually extract each object and encode to a byte string which can then be hashed using hashlib in python. However, my goal is to take the whole string and then encode so it looks like...myfile.encode('utf-8'). Printing myfile displays as follows >> {u'src':u'void', u'settings':u'my settings'}, is there anyway I can take the above unicoded string then encode to utf-8 to a sequence of bytes for hashlib.sha1(mayflies.encode('uff-8'). Do let me know for more clarification. Thanks in advance.

```
fileSRC = request.json['src']
fileSettings = request.json['settings']

myfile = request.json
print myfile

#hash the filename using sha1 from hashlib library
guid_object = hashlib.sha1(fileSRC.encode('utf-8')) // this works however I want myfile to be encoded not fileSRC
guid = guid_object.hexdigest() //this works 
print guid
```

Comment: Clarification: are you trying to make the json a string and hash that?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I got the answer from your question, it works now. Thank you so much.

Comment: I used ...jsonContent = json.dumps(request.json)..then                guid_object = hashlib.sha1(jsonContent.encode('utf-8')). This works now.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in comments, you solved your issue using:

```
jsonContent = json.dumps(request.json)
guid_object = hashlib.sha1(jsonContent.encode('utf-8'))
```

But it's important to understand why this works. Flask [sends you `unicode()` for non-ASCII, and `str()` for ASCII](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/unicode/). Dumping the result using JSON will give you consistent results since it abstracts away the internal Python representation, just as if you only had `unicode()`.

## Python 2

In Python 2 (the Python version you're using), you don't need `.encode('utf-8')` because the default value of `ensure_ascii` of `json.dumps()` is `True`. When you send non-ASCII data to `json.dumps()`, it will use JSON escape sequences to actually dump ASCII: no need to encode to UTF-8. Also, since the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says that "Explicit is better than implicit", even if `ensure_ascii` is already `True`, you could specify it:

```
jsonContent = json.dumps(request.json, ensure_ascii=True)
guid_object = hashlib.sha1(jsonContent)
```

## Python 3

In Python 3 however, this would no longer work. Inded, `json.dumps()` returns `unicode` in Python 3, even if everything in the `unicode` string is ASCII. But `hashlib.sha1` only works on `bytes`. You need to make the conversion explicit, even if the ASCII encoding is all you need:

```
jsonContent = json.dumps(request.json, ensure_ascii=True)
guid_object = hashlib.sha1(jsonContent.encode('ascii'))
```

This is why Python 3 is a better language: it forces you to be more explicit about the text you use, whether it is `str` (Unicode) or `bytes`. This avoids many, many problems down the road.