# python flask post data encoding

Tags: python, flask, encoding

I have a flask method which will take post data and do query, code like this

```
@app.route('/register/search', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(origin='*')
def register_search():
    json_data = request.get_json()
    param = {}
    if 'startrow' in request.json:
        param['startrow'] = request.json['startrow']
    if 'endrow' in request.json:
        param['endrow'] = request.json['endrow']
    if 'company_name' in request.json:
        param['company_name'] = request.json['company_name']
```

I use angular to do a reqest and company_name is 2 chinese character, but param['company_name'] 
get a string like this '\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87', how can I get original chinese character
from param['company_name']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got a solution for this:

**Wrong**
I got the posted problem if I use string concat for query like this:

```
sql = "select * from company where name like " + param['company_name']
cursor.execute(sql)
```

**Correct**

```
sql = "select * from company where name like %s"
cursor.execute(sql,("%"+param['company_name']+"%"))
```

use prepared statment, it will work

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

'\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87` looks like utf8 encoded unicode. 
Try this to convert it back to unicode:

```
param['company_name'] = request.json['company_name'].decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this method but got the following error message:  `param['company_name'] = request.json['company_name'].decode('utf-8')`   `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' ] `

Comment: are you using python2?

Comment: also have a look at this, it might help you solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658603